# Plus or minus minor glitch in my android calculator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calculator

I have made an android calculator, and I have added the +/- button to it recently. The problems I am facing is, firstly when I use it, and press the equal button, the app crashes. Moreover as soon as I click +/- button, the digits turn into a float value, and when I type any number the number value continues after the decimal. Example: I have 200 and I press +/- the number becomes 200.0 and when I type any number it becomes 200.01. How do I overcome this problem? Can someone please let me know what are the changes required in my code? Here it is.
Thank you. :)

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Typeface font1, font2;

    TextView tv1;
    private EditText Scr; //textbox screen
    private float NumberBf; //Save screen before pressing button operation;
    private String Operation;
    private ButtonClickListener btnClick;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        font1=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "digits.ttf");
        Scr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Scr.setTypeface(font1);
        font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "alexbrush.TTF");
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setTypeface(font2);
        Scr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Scr.setEnabled(false);
        btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
        int idList[] = {R.id.button0,R.id.button7, R.id.button1, R.id.button8,R.id.button9,R.id.button4,
                R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.buttonDot,
                R.id.buttonMul,R.id.buttonDiv,R.id.buttonAdd,R.id.buttonSub,R.id.buttonC,
                R.id.buttonEq, R.id.buttonSqrt, R.id.buttonsquare, R.id.buttonNp
        };

        for(int id:idList){
            View v = (View) findViewById(id);
            v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void mMath(String str){
        NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString()); //save the screen
        Operation = str; //save operation
        Scr.setText("0"); //Clear screen
    }

    public void getKeyboard(String str){
        String ScrCurrent = Scr.getText().toString();
        if(ScrCurrent.equals("0"))
            ScrCurrent = "";
        ScrCurrent += str;
        Scr.setText(ScrCurrent);
    }

    public void mResult(){
        float NumAf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
        float result = 0;
        if(Operation.equals("+")){
            result = NumAf + NumberBf;
        }
        if(Operation.equals("-")){
            result = NumberBf - NumAf;
        }
        if(Operation.equals("*")){
            result = NumAf * NumberBf;
        }
        if(Operation.equals("/")){
            result = NumberBf / NumAf;
        }
        Scr.setText(String.format("%10d", result));
    }

    public void fnSqrt(){
        double Number = Double.parseDouble(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number = Math.sqrt(Number);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
    }

    public void fnSquare(){
        float Number1 = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number1 = pow(Number1, 2);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number1));
    }

    public void fnNp(){
        float Number = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number = Number*(-1);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
        }

    private float pow(float number1, int i) {
        return number1*number1;
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonC: //Clear screen
                    Scr.setText("0");
                    NumberBf = 0;
                    Operation = "";
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonAdd: //function Add
                    mMath("+");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSub:
                    mMath("-");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonMul:
                    mMath("*");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonDiv:
                    mMath("/");
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonEq:
                    mResult();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSqrt:
                    fnSqrt();
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonNp:
                    fnNp();
                    break;    
                case R.id.buttonsquare:
                    fnSquare();
                    break;
                default:
                    String numb = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                    getKeyboard(numb);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: variables in Java should be `camelCase`. It's very confusing for experienced Java programmers to see variables that are `TitleCase` - we assume these are classes.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Since you mention the "+/-" button as being a single button I would think you are trying to use this button to change the sign of whatever your input is, but I don't see that case being handled anywhere in this code.  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: public void fnNp This is the function that is used for it.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first problem: Do you get a nullpointer exception?

```
public void mResult(){
    float NumAf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
```

does not prevents your statement to try to turn a null String into a float which obviously will let your app crash. So include a mechanism to catch the null value before.

```
case R.id.buttonEq:
    if (Scr.getText() != null)
        mResult();
    break;
```

I think this is the easiest way to prevent your `mResult()` from getting a null value.

For your second problem: It becomes a float because you do

```
float Number = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());`
```

When you cast your 200 into a float it becomes 200.00 which will be returned as a string.

EDIT: I realized that you also have a dotButton (your code is really messy). The suggested alternative of course does not work with decimal numbers because it always casts your `number`value. To prevent this behaviour maybe you can implement a simple if/else statement.

```
public void fnNp() {
    if (Scr.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
        float Number = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number = Number*(-1);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
    } else {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(Scr.getText().toString());
        Number = Number*(-1);
        Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a if statement in mResult that checks whether the float has a absolute difference to a float of the int of the float , less than , say Float.MIN_VALUE , and then get the toString of the int of the float instead if it is.

Wrap the call Scr.setText( Float f) , in a function setScreenTextWithNumber(Number n) 
and do the checking there.

If you just check for the decimal point, then 2.0000 / 2 = 1.000 if that is what you want.
Otherwise checking for significant differences makes a call that a number that is not significantly different from the nearest integer is an integer.